# A question about $A\times B\times C$ and $(A\times B)\times C$.

Tags: category-theory

> Let $\mathcal C$ be a category with products. Find a reasonable candidate for the universal property that the product $A\times B\times C$ of *three* objects of $\mathcal C$ ought to satisfy, and prove that both $(A\times B)\times C$ and $A\times(B\times C)$ satisfy this property.

I am trying to parse this statement, but ultimately becoming confused.

1. Isn't $A\times B\times C$ anyway the universal object in the category $\mathcal C_{A,B,C}$? Is there some other reasonable candidate that one should think of?
2. I will try and explain what I understand from $(A\times B)\times C$. First we determine the universal object in the category $\mathcal C_{A,B}$. Then we determine the universal object in the category of objects mapping to both $A\times B$ (which is the universal object of $\mathcal C_{A,B}$) and $C$. All the diagrams should commute, etc.

Is my understanding accurate? How do I *show* that $(A\times B)\times C$ satisfies this universal property?

Comment: Just a comment, but that is a nice exercise. Its books like this, that actually trust the reader to work out basic definitions for themselves (for example) that mathematics needs more of.

Comment: I think the universal property of $A \times B \times C$, together with the 'projections' $p: A\times B\times C \to A$, $q: A\times B\times C \to B$ and $r: A\times B\times C \to C$ should read as follows: given any object $X$ of $\mathcal{C}$ and a triple $(f,g,h)$ of morphisms $f:X\to A$, $g:X\to B$, $h:X\to C$, there exists a unique morphism $s: X \to A\times B\times C$ such that $f =p\circ s$, $g = q\circ s$ and $h =r\circ s$.

Comment: @ivanpenev- Yes, have I written something different?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that $C_{A,B,C}$ means what I think it does, item 1 of your question is the correct answer for "find a reasonable candidate $\dots$", and I can't think of another reasonable candidate (though I might just not be imaginative enough). You understanding of $(A\times B)\times C$ is correct also.  To show that it satisfies the definition of $A\times B\times C$, let $p_{A\times B}$ and $p_C$ be its projections to $A\times B$ and to $C$; also, let $q_A$ and $q_B$ be the projections of $A\times B$ to $A$ and to $B$.  Then $q_A\circ p_{A\times B}$,  $q_B\circ p_{A\times B}$, and $p_C$ are the three projections of $(A\times B)\times C$ that should have the universal property that defines $A\times B\times C$.  Verifying the universal property is routine, though a bit tedious, so I won't write out the details here.

Comment: What is the universal property that $A\times B\times C$ sought to satisfy? That it is a final product? That every object has a unique morphism to it?

Comment: @user1992 Right. For any object $X$ and morphisms from it to each of $A,B,C$, there should be a unique morphism from $X$ to $(A\times B)\times C$ which, together with the alleged projections, makes the three triangles commute.